# is there an way to run towice vue apps in one index.html First vue Version is 3 and second vue app version is 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router

I created two apps with vue framework, and i want to combine them together in one directory to be like this:
https://host.com/ => runs first vue  app EX: Website Store.
https://host.com/admin => runs second vue app EX: Dashboard of the website.
can i find any way to do this ??
i tried to put dashboard build in ./admin/index.html and wbsite in ./index.html
but when i run it website works well but the admin path giving me Error 404 he can't find some chuncks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your .htaccess file in your subdirectory so be able to run vue app on it. I don't think vuejs version matter !

if your subdirectory is **admin** you should use this config (in yourdomain.com/admin/.htaccess file) :

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . admin/index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```